# Как называется текст

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Как называется текст, который появляется после нажатия на инлайн-кнопку в канале?
Как мне сделать такое сообщение через aiogram на pythone[image: я нажал на кнопку и появился такой текст]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эти 2 вида сообщений:

```
 bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=cmd.id, text="Изменять голос запрещено", show_alert=False)

    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=cmd.id, text="Неверно, Верный ответ...", show_alert=True)
```

[image: ы]

[image: 2]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @IlmirSharifullin если ответ вам подошел отмечайте его как правильный)